# How to design spatial database for Building

Tags: postgresql, database-design, gis, postgis

Currently I am doing an internship for developing spatial database for buildings. What I am trying to do is to build spatial database model for buildings which informs information such as floors, typical building, tenants, address and other reliable information.

The main purpose of this spatial database is to be used for urban spatial analysis. I am using PostgreSQL for the database.

Currently I have polygon features data represent as buildings and feature points (centroid) of the building data with approximately 350 buildings. What I have done so far is creating table which store information as below

Polygon feature building table

```
|id | name | address | districts | longitude | latitude | geometry |
```

Points building table

```
|id | name | address | districts | longitude | latitude | geometry |
```

relationship table of the building

```
|id_building | floors | tenant | phone | status |
```

The tenant on some building is mainly temporary so it will changes periodically. Do I need make a relationship table on this spatial database? does the relationship table will be affecting the performance of the database or should it be stores in single tables instead?

Comment: This question is not about programming. I think https://gis.stackexchange.com/ (one of our sister site) is a better place on getting inputs on how to deal with changing building data.

Comment: Thanks!! I'll moved to gis.stackexchange

Comment: pretty sure this will be voted as too broad or recommended to move to DBA.SE instead, over at GIS.SE. in general, the spatial component has no effect on usual DB normalization rules. if you want to have separate tables for polygon and point geometries depends on your use case (it's better for indexing, though). `lat/lon` columns are somewhat redundant when you have geometries, and don't make much sense for polygons (if not for their centroids)

Answer (score 1):

it is not necessary to store a building or an object in both polygon and point tables, and in order to store properties use hstrore field.
I suggest you to visit openstreetmap design table:https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Database